# Using backreference after RewriteCond in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, backreference

I have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=search&keyword=$1
```

Input:

```
my.domain.com/foo_bar
```

I want:

```
index.php?q=search&keyword=foo_bar
```

But in fact:

```
index.php?q=search&keyword=index.php
```

I don't understand why. Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewrite rule is actually rewriting twice, once for `/foo_bar` and second time for `index.php` as `.*` matches anything.

You just need to add 2 conditions to stop rewrite for files and directories:

```
# handle landing page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php?q=search [L,QSA]

# handle /foo_bar
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my\.domain\.com$ [NC]
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?q=search&keyword=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It worked. But it also change my url path. I have "domain.com" and the subdomain "my.domain.com" point to 1 directory together. The htaccess file is in the root. I want to write above code for detect when url is my.domain.com. But I also want keep the subdomain in url. Your code change url to: domain.com/search/foo_bar. I expected: my.domain.com/foo_bar instead. Thank you!

Comment: No this rule is not changing URL (it is just internal rewrite). You have either old browser cache or some other rules. Make sure you test after clearing browser cache and test with only this rule in .htaccess

Comment: Can u teach me some more? If I want 2 rewriterule, for example: "my.domain.com => index.php?q=search" and "my.domain.com/foo_bar => index.php?q=search&keyword=foo_bar" then I must dupplicate the RewriteCond? I heard that one RewriteCond only active to one RewriteRule after it.